# override pack/grid behaviour

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

i'm trying to make a custom widget that to provide a scrollable frame that resizes to fit its contents or window, eg is the contents of the inner frame is smaller than the view of the canvas then the contents can be stretched to fit the view, or if they are smaller scrollbars can be enabled, however to make the use simpler i want to be able to override whatever methods are needed to pack or grid widgets inside the inner frame. eg instead of:
    tk.Button(scrollframe.inner, ...)
i want to be able to use:
    tk.Button(scrollframe, ...)

however i can't work out how to do that, my code is currently:

```
__all__ = ['ScrolledFrame']

try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

class ScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.scrollbars = None
        self.scroll_shown= [False, False]
        if ('scrollbars' in kwargs):
            self.scrollbars = kwargs['scrollbars']
            del kwargs['scrollbars']

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical')
        self.hsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal')
        self.vsb.opts = {'column':2, 'row':1, 'sticky':'nesw'}
        self.hsb.opts = {'column':1, 'row':2, 'sticky':'nesw'}

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                                yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set,
                                xscrollcommand=self.hsb.set)
        self.canvas.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='nesw')

        self.vsb.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.hsb.config(command=self.canvas.xview)

        self.canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        self.canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self._reconfigure)

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)

        self.frame_id = self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self.frame, anchor='nw')

        self.frame.bind('<Configure>', self._reconfigure)

        self.update_idletasks()
        self._showscrollbars()

    def _reconfigure(self, event=None):
        f_reqsize = (self.frame.winfo_reqwidth(), self.frame.winfo_reqheight())
        c_size = (self.canvas.winfo_width(), self.canvas.winfo_height())
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 %s %s" % f_reqsize)
        if (f_reqsize[0] < c_size[0]):
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.frame_id, width=c_size[0])
        else:
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.frame_id, width=f_reqsize[0])
        if (f_reqsize[1] < c_size[1]):
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.frame_id, height=c_size[1])
        else:
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.frame_id, height=f_reqsize[1])

        if (self.scrollbars == 'auto'):
            self._showscrollbars()

    def _showscrollbars(self):
        if (self.scrollbars == 'both'):
            self.vsb.grid(**self.vsb.opts)
            self.hsb.grid(**self.hsb.opts)
        elif (self.scrollbars == 'x'):
            self.vsb.grid_remove()
            self.hsb.grid(**self.hsb.opts)
        elif (self.scrollbars == 'y'):
            self.vsb.grid(**self.vsb.opts)
            self.hsb.grid_remove()
        elif (self.scrollbars == 'auto'):
            f_reqsize = (self.frame.winfo_reqwidth(), self.frame.winfo_reqheight())
            c_size = (self.canvas.winfo_width(), self.canvas.winfo_height())
            # start with vertical
            if self.scroll_shown[1] == False: # not showing
                if (f_reqsize[1] > c_size[1]): # height is greater than canvas so show
                    self.canvas.configure(width=self.canvas.winfo_width() - self.vsb.winfo_reqwidth())
                    self.vsb.grid(**self.vsb.opts)
                    self.scroll_shown[1] = True
            else:
                if (f_reqsize[1] <= c_size[1]): # height is less than canvas so don't show
                    self.vsb.grid_remove()
                    self.canvas.configure(width=self.canvas.winfo_width() + self.vsb.winfo_reqwidth())
                    self.scroll_shown[1] = False

            # now horizontal
            if self.scroll_shown[0] == False: # not showing
                if (f_reqsize[0] > c_size[0]): # width is greater than canvas so show
                    self.canvas.configure(height=self.canvas.winfo_height() - self.hsb.winfo_reqheight())
                    self.hsb.grid(**self.hsb.opts)
                    self.scroll_shown[0] = True
            else:
                if (f_reqsize[0] <= c_size[0]): # width is less than canvas so don't show
                    self.hsb.grid_remove()
                    self.canvas.configure(height=self.canvas.winfo_height() + self.hsb.winfo_reqheight())
                    self.scroll_shown[0] = False

    def resize(self):
        self._reconfigure()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    frames = []
    def add_row():
        frame = tk.Frame(sf.frame)
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        num = len(frames)
        tk.Label(frame, text='Test %i' % num).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="nesw")
        tk.Entry(frame).grid(column=2, row=1, sticky="nesw")
        frame.grid(column=1, row=num, sticky='nesw')
        sf.frame.grid_rowconfigure(num, weight=1)
        frames.append(frame)
        sf.resize()

    def del_row():
        frame = frames.pop()
        frame.grid_forget()
        frame.destroy()
        num = len(frames)
        sf.frame.grid_rowconfigure(num, weight=0)
        sf.resize()

    def add_column():
        pass

    def del_column():
        pass

    root = tk.Tk()

    sf = ScrolledFrame(root, scrollbars='auto')
    sf.frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    sf.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, sticky='nesw')
    tk.Button(root, text='-', command=del_row).grid(column=3, row=1, sticky='nesw')
    tk.Button(root, text='+', command=add_row).grid(column=3, row=2, sticky='nesw')
    tk.Button(root, text='-', command=del_column).grid(column=1, row=3, sticky='nesw')
    tk.Button(root, text='+', command=add_column).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky='nesw')

    root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

    root.mainloop()
```

so in the test code in the bottom of my sketch i want to change the add function so that its `frame = tk.Frame(sf)` without interfering with the ability to pack/grid the outer frame into a parent window/frame, how do i do this/what methods/attributes to i need to override?

I tried overriding `__str__` and `__repr__` to point at the inner frames methodswithout success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute you are looking for is `_w`. However just using that won't get what you want. The problem is that you need to pass some attributes to the outer frame and others to the inner frame. You can sort out what goes where by comparing to an uninitialized Widget. However it's very hard to route that from a Widget subclass since you would need to override attributes. It's much easier to make a normal class (not a subclass) and route the attributes from that:

```
__all__ = ['ScrolledFrame']

try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

class ScrolledFrame:
    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.scrollbars = kwargs.pop('scrollbars', None)
        self.scroll_shown= [False, False]

        self.outer_attr = set(dir(tk.Widget)) # a list of attributes that the outer frame should handle
        self.outer_frame = tk.Frame(master)

        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.outer_frame, orient='vertical')
        self.hsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.outer_frame, orient='horizontal')
        self.vsb.opts = {'column':2, 'row':1, 'sticky':'nesw'}
        self.hsb.opts = {'column':1, 'row':2, 'sticky':'nesw'}

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.outer_frame, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                                yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set,
                                xscrollcommand=self.hsb.set)
        self.canvas.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='nesw')

        self.vsb.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.hsb.config(command=self.canvas.xview)

        self.canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        self.canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self._reconfigure)

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)

        self.frame_id = self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self.frame, anchor='nw')

        self.frame.bind('<Configure>', self._reconfigure)

        #~ self.update_idletasks() # this is not needed; and should never be needed.
        self._showscrollbars()

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        '''when an attribute is requested, sort out which frame should provide the attribute'''
        if item in self.outer_attr:
            # geometry attributes etc (eg pack, destroy, tkraise) are passed on to self.outer
            return getattr(self.outer_frame, item)
        else:
            # all other attributes (_w, children, etc) are passed to self.inner
            return getattr(self.frame, item)

    def _reconfigure(self, event=None):
        f_reqsize = (self.frame.winfo_reqwidth(), self.frame.winfo_reqheight())
        c_size = (self.canvas.winfo_width(), self.canvas.winfo_height())
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 %s %s" % f_reqsize)
        if (f_reqsize[0] < c_size[0]):
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.frame_id, width=c_size[0])
        else:
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.frame_id, width=f_reqsize[0])
        if (f_reqsize[1] < c_size[1]):
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.frame_id, height=c_size[1])
        else:
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.frame_id, height=f_reqsize[1])

        if (self.scrollbars == 'auto'):
            self._showscrollbars()

    def _showscrollbars(self):
        if (self.scrollbars == 'both'):
            self.vsb.grid(**self.vsb.opts)
            self.hsb.grid(**self.hsb.opts)
        elif (self.scrollbars == 'x'):
            self.vsb.grid_remove()
            self.hsb.grid(**self.hsb.opts)
        elif (self.scrollbars == 'y'):
            self.vsb.grid(**self.vsb.opts)
            self.hsb.grid_remove()
        elif (self.scrollbars == 'auto'):
            f_reqsize = (self.frame.winfo_reqwidth(), self.frame.winfo_reqheight())
            c_size = (self.canvas.winfo_width(), self.canvas.winfo_height())
            # start with vertical
            if self.scroll_shown[1] == False: # not showing
                if (f_reqsize[1] > c_size[1]): # height is greater than canvas so show
                    self.canvas.configure(width=self.canvas.winfo_width() - self.vsb.winfo_reqwidth())
                    self.vsb.grid(**self.vsb.opts)
                    self.scroll_shown[1] = True
            else:
                if (f_reqsize[1] <= c_size[1]): # height is less than canvas so don't show
                    self.vsb.grid_remove()
                    self.canvas.configure(width=self.canvas.winfo_width() + self.vsb.winfo_reqwidth())
                    self.scroll_shown[1] = False

            # now horizontal
            if self.scroll_shown[0] == False: # not showing
                if (f_reqsize[0] > c_size[0]): # width is greater than canvas so show
                    self.canvas.configure(height=self.canvas.winfo_height() - self.hsb.winfo_reqheight())
                    self.hsb.grid(**self.hsb.opts)
                    self.scroll_shown[0] = True
            else:
                if (f_reqsize[0] <= c_size[0]): # width is less than canvas so don't show
                    self.hsb.grid_remove()
                    self.canvas.configure(height=self.canvas.winfo_height() + self.hsb.winfo_reqheight())
                    self.scroll_shown[0] = False

    def resize(self):
        self._reconfigure()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    frames = []
    def add_row():
        frame = tk.Frame(sf)
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        num = len(frames)
        tk.Label(frame, text='Test %i' % num).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="nesw")
        tk.Entry(frame).grid(column=2, row=1, sticky="nesw")
        frame.grid(column=1, row=num, sticky='nesw')
        sf.frame.grid_rowconfigure(num, weight=1)
        frames.append(frame)
        sf.resize()

    def del_row():
        frame = frames.pop()
        frame.grid_forget()
        frame.destroy()
        num = len(frames)
        sf.frame.grid_rowconfigure(num, weight=0)
        sf.resize()

    def add_column():
        pass

    def del_column():
        pass

    root = tk.Tk()

    sf = ScrolledFrame(root, scrollbars='auto')
    sf.frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    sf.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, sticky='nesw')
    tk.Button(root, text='-', command=del_row).grid(column=3, row=1, sticky='nesw')
    tk.Button(root, text='+', command=add_row).grid(column=3, row=2, sticky='nesw')
    tk.Button(root, text='-', command=del_column).grid(column=1, row=3, sticky='nesw')
    tk.Button(root, text='+', command=add_column).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky='nesw')

    root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

    root.mainloop()
```

A big drawback to this solution is that the automatic `self.master` does not work. When you add a widget to this "frame", it's `self.master` chain is the inner Frame > Canvas > outer Frame. That means if you subclass this you have to pass the instance explicitly because the "children" have no built in way to access it.

I have solved this problem before when I was trying to make a ScrolledFrame widget. [Here's my code, if you are interested](https://gist.github.com/novel-yet-trivial/3eddfce704db3082e38c84664fc1fdf8) which solves a couple more problems like cross platform mouse wheel binding.

Comment: thanks, i like that, seems as elegant a solution as possible, my main reasons for making yet another scrolled frame class (i know there are a few out there on the internet) is that they all seemed lacking in some way, such as scrolling bugs (if the inner contents are smaller than the canvas) or they didn't allow the inner contents to be stretched to fit the canvas frame if desired. my current version has got bindings added for the mouse, including linux, mac and windows, but i left this out for a shorter example.

Comment: likewise if you are interested my updated code is now here: https://github.com/JamesGKent/python-tkwidgets/blob/master/scrollableframe.py